# Detect usage of Google Cast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-tv

How to detect if my **AndroidTV is currently** an Google Cast **receiver** from mobile/desktop ?

How to detect **who is currently** an Google Cast **sender** from Google Cast Receiver perspective?

How to detect if my **Android Phone is currently** an Google Cast **sender**?

Comment: Please, if possible,  explain why you would need to have that information, what is your use case?

Comment: I'd like to make stats what way is android tv used and is android phone used as remote control.

Comment: To add to this, I'd like this functionality, to run a watcher app that turns on my tv/speakers via Harmony when it detects a cast has begun

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use the Android Media Router API to request all available routes to Cast devices. Then you would then have to connect to each Cast device and then you can determine the app ID or even if media is playing. If you only want to know if your own app is running, then simply filter the Media Router request by that.
2. Only the receiver would know which senders are connected to it. In your own custom receiver you could keep track of that for your own app.
3. You might be able to use the Media Router to determine if there is an active route. Not sure if you will be able to tell if it is a Cast route, since these routes could also go to other devices like bluetooth speakers.

Comment: Seems promising but could you be more specific about which Android Media Router API classes could I use ?

Comment: Take a look at this sample: https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

Answer (score 0):

To add to Leons answer, we have a callback on the MediaRouter like so to get callback on when our chromecast receiver app is selected

```
val mMediaRouterCallback = object : MediaRouter.Callback() {
    override fun onRouteSelected(router: MediaRouter?, route: MediaRouter.RouteInfo?) {
        routeInfo = route
    }
    override // override appropriate methods here!!
}
val mMediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
    .addControlCategory(
        CastMediaControlIntent
            .categoryForCast(BuildConfig.CHROMECAST_RECEIVER_APP_ID)
    ).build()

MediaRouter.getInstance(context).addCallback(
    mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
    MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN
)
```

Build selector to work for more than one app. And it is possible to change `MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN` to broaden your scan.

Comment: Isn't it is the API for the **sender** to select which **receiver** to be cast to? The OP want to opposite one. He is the receiver and would like to know weather a sender is connected to or what the sender is.

Comment: I think it is possible to automatically connect to a receiver if that is what you mean. The receiver software is completely different, take a look here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/web_receiver