# Android TV Chromecast: detect if a phone(sender) is video casting to Android TV (receiver)

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, android-tv

I would like to detect if Android TV is being video casting (connected from phone (sender) ).

Android TV has the system app (Chromecast build-in) pre-installed. I would like to know if there is events that a phone is connected or just disconnected for video casting.

Or do I need to develop custom Chromecast receiver app just in order to catch those events?

Found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58655387/1099884, but it is not what I needed. I would like the opposite usage. (My device is receiver while the others are sender)